# make: *** [makefile:135: obj/bitvector.o] Error 1

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the tool Shapeit5.
After running the make command the tool give the following warning:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -mavx2 -mfma -D__COMMIT_ID__="3d97fcd" -D__COMMIT_DATE__="2023-10-02" -c src/containers/bitvector.cpp -o obj/bitvector.o -Isrc -I/opt/tools/htslib/opt/tools/htslib -I/opt/tools/boost_1_73_0/boost/include
In file included from src/containers/bitvector.h:26,from src/containers/bitvector.cpp:23:
src/utils/otools.h:52:10: fatal error: htslib/hts.h: No such file or directory
52 | #include <htslib/hts.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:135: obj/bitvector.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand if the problem is related to the makefile I filled or rather to a system problem.
Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

Kind regards.

Stefano

Tryed to re-install the software along with all the dependences

Comment: Its saying it cant find the htslib code, which means you have to install htslib https://github.com/samtools/htslib

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely that your command line is setup incorrectly.   Notice you have the gcc command line option:

`-I/opt/tools/htslib/opt/tools/htslib`

This means in order for `#include <htslib/hts.h>` to work, the `hts.h` file would have to live in `/opt/tools/htslib/opt/tools/htslib/htslib/hts.h`.   You should do

`find /opt/tools/htslib/opt/tools/htslib -name hts.h`

(assuming you're using linux), to see where this lives.   If the htslib directory itself does not exist, you need to either install htslib or adjust the command line argument to point to the directory where htslib is installed.  If it does exist, but the `hts.h` file is not in an `htslib` subdirectory, you either need to modify the c files to point to the right subdirectories, or modify the makefile to include the correct path.